# Split a huge excel file into multiple files

Tags: python, excel, vba, file

I have a very huge excel file. There's "------------" this string between a few rows. I'd like to divide the files from "------------" to another "------------" and name them with the word that's in "------------"'s next cell. Please help me on doing this.

Comment: Can you upload a sample xls spreadsheet to test on? Will it always be the cell next to the "------------" ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelkader It will always be the cell next to "------------"

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @MarkSetchell If you meant OS, I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use something like: http://www.python-excel.org/.

```
pip install xlrd xlwt
```

**xlrd** - reads Excel files

**xlwt** - writes Excel files

I would then attempt something like this:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

def write_rows(batch, filename):
    current_batch_xls = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    first_sheet = current_batch_xls.add_sheet(filename + ' sheet')
    for row_number, row in enumerate(batch):
        for cell_number, cell in enumerate(row):
            first_sheet.write(row_number, cell_number, cell.value, style=cell.xf_index)
    current_batch_xls.save(filename)

FILENAME='big-excel-spreadsheet.xls'
DELIMITER='------------'
big_spreadsheet = xlrd.open_workbook(FILENAME)
# assuming you have only one sheet
sheet = big_spreadsheet.sheet_by_index(0)
current_batch_of_rows = []
for row in xrange(2, sheet.nrows):
    if row.cell(row, 0) == DELIMITER:
        write_rows(current_batch_of_rows, filename=row.cell(row, 1))
        current_batch_of_rows = []
        continue
    current_batch_of_rows.append(sheet.row(row))
```

Untested. Docs seem pretty terrible for `xlrd` and `xlwt`.